# Changing limits when switching order of integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Consider the following Lebesgue integral:
>   $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{|f|>y} g(y) \: |f(x)| \: \mathrm{d}x \: \mathrm{d}y , $$
>   where g is a non-negative measurable function defined on $ (0,\infty) $ and $ f $ is a measurable function defined on $ \mathbb{R}^n $. If I am correct, the *Tonelli's version of the Fubini theorem* allows us to switch the order of integration. **Question:** What will be the new limits of integration?

**My attempt:**
\begin{align}
\{(x,y) : |f(x)|>y, \: y \in (0,\infty)\} &= \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \: |f(x)|>y, \: y \in (0,\infty)\} \\
&= \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \: |f(x)|>y>0\} .
\end{align}
Hence, the above double integral equals
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f|} g(y) \: |f(x)| \: \mathrm{d}y \: \mathrm{d}x . $$
While I have no doubt that the the two integrals are indeed equal, I'm wondering whether the set-theoretic justification I gave is sufficient, or whether I missed some subtlety?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general thoughts are right but you made some (minor) mistakes or should consider points you might not realized before:

1.) you missed to switch "dx" and "dy" at the end, so the correct term is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f|} g(y) \: |f(x)| \: \mathrm{d}y \: \mathrm{d}x$$

2.) You should recognize that actually your domain of the outer integral should be $$\Bbb R^n\setminus\{|f| \not=0 \}$$.

Because the integrand contains $|f|$ as a factor and so equals $0$ if $|f|=0$ this doesn't matter in your case but if the integrand would be e.g. $$g(x)\left(|f(x)| + 1\right)$$ it could!

Just be aware of that....

Comment: Thank you for this answer! As to your first point, I forgot to switch "dx" and "dy" because I copied and pasted. Have fixed it now, thanks for pointing it out! Regarding your second point, don't we have $ \int_{0}^{0} g(y) \: |f(x)| \: \mathrm{d}y = 0 $, in which case it doesn't make a difference whether the domain for the outer integral is $ \mathbb{R}^n $ or $ \Bbb R^n\setminus\{|f| \not=0 \} $, regardless of the integrand? I would be grateful for more explanation! Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right… but still. This only fit's here because of the domain you integrate over. If you are aware of it => great :-) Just try your transformation with$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{|f| + 1>y} g(y) \: (|f(x)|+1) \: \mathrm{d}x \: \mathrm{d}y $$ and it should play a role :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f| + 1} g(y) \: (|f(x)|+1) \: \mathrm{d}y \: \mathrm{d}x $? I struggle to see why we have to exclude $ \{x : |f| = 0 \} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ from the outer integration domain... If it is necessary as you say, though, I would be very grateful if you could explain it in more detail. Many thanks! :)

Comment: As you said in your initial question the integration domain is $$\{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \: |f(x)|>y>0\}$$ and this imply $$|f(x)| > 0$$, hence $$|f| \not=0$$. But $$\Bbb R^n = \{ |f| > 0\} \cup \{ |f| = 0 \}$$ so the correct outer integration domain has to be $$\Bbb R^n \setminus \{ |f| = 0 \} =  \{ |f| > 0\}$$. You can verify this by calculating the initial expression $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{|f| + 1>y} g(y) \: (|f(x)|+1) \: \mathrm{d}x \: \mathrm{d}y$$ and your "solution" $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f| + 1} g(y) \: (|f(x)|+1) \: \mathrm{d}y \: \mathrm{d}x$$ for $f \equiv 0$

Answer (score 1):

If the set $E$ is defined as

$$ E = \{ (x, y) : |f(x)| > y \} $$

then the function $(x, y) \mapsto g(y)|f(x)| \mathbf{1}_E(x, y)$ is non-negative and measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)$, and hence by the Tonelli's theorem

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{|f(x)|>y} g(y)|f(x)| \, dxdy
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(y)|f(x)|\mathbf{1}_E(x, y) \, dxdy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(y)|f(x)|\mathbf{1}_E(x, y) \, dydx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f(x)|} g(y)|f(x)| \, dydx
\end{align*}

That being said, the only subtlety you have to deal with is the measurability of the set $E$, but this is rather obvious from the measurability of the function $(x, y) \mapsto f(x) - y$.